# Kids' book about what life will be like for a kid in the year 3000

Tags: story-identification, books

So in this book it talks about what life will be like in the year 3000. They talk about how animals will be able to talk using special collars and hoverboard parks, they also talked about how scientists made fruits and veggies taste like pizza and junk food.

Comment: Do you remember estimated size of this book? Was it just a short story, or great novel ?

Comment: I heard not much has changed, 'cept they live underwater.

Comment: @CandiedMango And your great-great-great-granddaughter is doing fine, too.

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be looking for [2030: A Day in the Life of Tomorrow's Kids](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0525478604). Features hoverboards and talking pets.

> "Inspired and informed by trends and scientifi c and technological
>   research, 2030 is not only a peek at some cool future gadgets (talking
>   dog collars, cars that drive themselves), but also a thoughtful
>   examination of how our lives might be impacted as we adjust to
>   environmental change."

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at "The Beast" by RL Stine? [or possibly the sequel, it's been years and I don't recall]

I'll come right out and say it doesn't seem like a good match on the surface, since summaries are about a haunted roller coaster.
It is a kids or YA book, not very long (physically thin) and it contains a spiel about 'the future' and what it will be like which reminded me of your question - but there's a lot more to the book that you don't mention, so it's a possibility, not a certainty?

But there is time travel involved, in the book, the coaster takes a couple kids from the present day back in time, and in the past they are collected by someone who knows they're from out-of-time and forced to perform as "kids from the future" (they're not from 3000, but they might be advertised as such?)  including exaggerated or outright fictional accounts of what hopes and fears have come to pass, what has historically been accomplished, what's commonplace, and what's still recognizable.

I seem to recall that braces are passed off as a class marking (royalty or something, because jewelry for teeth).  There is ridiculous (shiny silver or the like) clothing and accessories, because real future clothing was too shocking or too ordinary (a girl in knee shorts and a tank top pretended her dress was stolen, because modern clothes were easily mistaken for what was to be worn under a dress back then).  I think the spiel the kids had to memorize also mentioned talking animals and flying skateboards.  I think at one point one of the kids goes off script, because they're mad at being forced into performing and how ridiculous the future-spiel sounded even though the guy had access to real future-kids, and the kid talks to the audience about junk food and social inequality and basically how the 'real' future is actually recognizable, not a shiny entertainment.

Like I said, not sure if this is it, but your question brought it to mind so I thought I'd offer.  I hope this helps.